# Can I record cameraview with mediarecorder?

Tags: java, mediarecorder

I am really struggling trying to record the cameraview. I want to record the view when start recording is clicked.

```
<com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:cameraFacing="front"/>
```

I only get a metafile and stopping the recording fails.

public void startRecording() throws IOException {

```
    // Creating file
    File dir = MainActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir("test/" + currentFolderName);
    try {
        videofile = File.createTempFile("video", ".mp4", dir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "External storage access error");
        return;
    }
    Log.i("CAMERA","Recording");
    // Creating MediaRecorder and specifying video source, output format, encoder, and output file

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFile(videofile.getAbsolutePath());


    recorder.prepare();
    Surface surface = recorder.getSurface();
    recorder.start();
}
```

public void stopRecording() {

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                recorder.stop();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error stopping MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, 500); // Add a 500ms delay before stopping the recording
    recorder.reset();
    recorder.release();
    // After stopping the recorder, create the video file and add it to the media library
    addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
}
protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
    // Creating content values
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "video" + videofile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videofile.getAbsolutePath());

    // Creating content resolver and storing it in the external content uri
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri base = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

    // Sending broadcast message to scan the media file so that it can be available
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I get Error stopping MediaRecorder. I think I'm not starting recording on the correct source but I've ran out of ideas.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.